# how do I implement an id lock in rust?

Tags: rust, mutex

I have to lock different process which identified by an id.

So I write the codes as below:

```rust
use std::collections::HashMap;
use std::ptr::null;
use std::sync::{Arc, Mutex, MutexGuard};

pub struct IDMutex {
    m: Mutex<HashMap<String, Arc<Mutex<u8>>>>,
}

pub struct IDMutexGuard<'a> {
    mutex: &'a IDMutex,
    local_mutex: Arc<Mutex<u8>>,
    local_guard: *const MutexGuard<'a, u8>,
    id: String,
}

impl<'a> IDMutexGuard<'a> {
    fn new(mutex: &'a IDMutex, id: String) -> Self {
        let mut guard: MutexGuard<'_, _> = mutex.m.lock().unwrap();
        let local_mutex = guard.entry(id.clone()).or_default().clone();

        let mut res = Self {
            mutex,
            id,
            local_mutex: local_mutex,
            local_guard: null(),
        };
        res.local_guard = &res.local_mutex.lock().unwrap();
        res
    }
}

impl<'a> Drop for IDMutexGuard<'a> {
    fn drop(&mut self) {
        drop(&mut self.local_guard);
        let mut guard = self.mutex.m.lock().unwrap();
        guard.remove(&self.id);
    }
}

impl IDMutex {
    fn lock(&self, id: String) -> IDMutexGuard<'_> {
        IDMutexGuard::new(&self, id)
    }
}
```

It is implemented like standard library's Mutex and MutexGuard, but with an id parameter so that I can lock for some id.  But it doesn't build because of the borrowed rules.

So is there any ideas about solve these problems?

I know that the correct way is to pick out the shared states and just use the standard library's mutex to lock them. But it's realy a challenged way for some history reasons and I hope I will do it in the future.

Comment: from looking at it i have absolutly no idea what your code should do, can you add soe comments?

Comment: Could you please explain your use case in a bit more detail? You are asking about a specific way of addressing your problem. I feel that way is more compicated than it needs to be, but it's hard to tell without understanding the underlying problem.

Comment: What does it mean to lock a *process*? I haven't heard this phrase before and Googling doesn't bring up anything enlightening. Usually we speak about locking resources, like files and (for threads) shared memory. Intuitively I would assume that locking a process implies suspending it, but I don't see anything in your code related to multiprocessing so I think I must be misunderstanding.

Comment: I can say for sure that `drop(&mut self.local_guard)` doesn't do anything useful. You'd need `std::ptr::drop_in_place` to drop the guard on the other end of the pointer, and you'd need to derereference it. But that would also be wrong, because in `new` the pointer is initialized to the address of a local variable that will be dropped when `new` returns. So that's certainly not doing what you want.

Answer (score 0):

> So is there any ideas about solve these problems?

Don't create your own MutexGuard built on the existing. It's not really doable because you need to return both the owned Mutex and the MutexGuard as the latter borrows the former. Furthermore the owned Mutex is really borrowed from the Arc so you need to return *that* as well. But the act of returning the Arc moves it, which is not allowed because then the references may be invalidated.

Don't create your own MutexGuard using low-level code either, that's possible but not easy.

I see two ways of getting out of the connundrum:

1. Use a callback-based system, have your API manage the locks and the caller provide a FnOnce you call with the information, this is pretty limiting but it's very simple for both caller and callee.
2. Return the `Arc` you cloned from the map, and let the caller handle locking it. That's pretty important because due to the way your setup is designed it's normal to lock the map, get the item, then unlock the map *while you're still holding onto the item*, which means a caller may want to `try_lock` the second lock.